# Failed to pass the challenge for domain

Tags: java, ssl, lets-encrypt

Using `certbot` fails to generate certificate with this error:

```
org.shredzone.acme4j.exception.AcmeException: Failed to pass the challenge for domain www.
mysampledomain123.com, ... Giving up.
```

I manually checked the challenge file and got

```
http://www.mysampledomain123.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/jU--PkDrn5tDZw2RN6NNJHbPD00ovHFkLFvN3mJdeQX
```

Inside the file:

```
jU--PkDrn5tDZw2RN6NNJHbPD00ovHFkLFvN3mJdeQX.tuMr-UijwpsJ1KVZkdWTYgodWZ2SxxKdB7_CMAAEfpg
```

And here's the complete HTTP response header:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Sun, 16 Feb 2020 14:15:22 GMT
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept
X-Powered-By: MyServer
X-RateLimit-Limit: 1000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 999
X-RateLimit-Reset: 0
```

I'm wondering whether the problem is with the HTTP response headers or the content itself. 
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the certbot command you used to request your cert?

Comment: Actually - I just noticed this: Your file contents exactly match your file name. In my case, my file contents consisted of the file name, followed by a period, followed by additional content (another long string of text). Worth double-checking?

Comment: Thanks for checking, I have updated the question with the correct file content.

Comment: OK - yes that is odd.  If the file's content is being served at the expected URL - then I don't know what might cause this issue. My only other suggestion is: Can you use the [DNS challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/) instead of the HTTP challenge?

Comment: @andrewjames apparently DNS challenge would not be possible since the app is about automating the SSL certificate generation process and DNS challenge can't be automated. Issue related to this is already filled to the library: https://github.com/shred/acme4j/issues/86